# How to disable default % applying behaviour in Excel?

Tags: excel

Whenever I insert % symbol at the end of a string in a cell it will automatically convert to percent format, i.e. the value is divided by 100. I want to disable the auto convert to % type and only string is allowed. How will I do that?

Comment: So I tend to do my percent calculations in the "raw" ie "=x/y**100" and don't format as % or type % at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mechanism to set the cell value datatype as number, string, percentage as fixed depends on the user data. Prefixing `'` works for only one cell. User have to prefix all the cell value with `'` that is not the ideal approach. If the column is set to general then the appends `%` at the end of any value then it will be converted to percent not to string. User again have to modify the cell datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult. The only way I could prevent the percentage calculation was by inserting an other charakter first. Not all where working. Blank Space is not working. ' is not working.

But these are working, but they are invisible, which can make problems.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quote the cell with an apostrophe: `'100%`. This will force the type of a cell to string, which means the percent sign is part of the cell.

Or use a custom number format: `0%`. In this case the percent sign is not part of the cell. You even do not have to type it.

In most cases the last approach is better, because you can still calculate with the cell. But when you export the table, you will loose the percent sign. In this case the first alternative may be better.

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17LnWQztuV9JvMt1A-pVsWGjkLIP6XL0ytJRCkoWzPjc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried this in my example above, it is not working

Comment: @Prema It is working till ages.

Comment: can you look at the picture! I wrote
'5% in the column H with general formatting and in column F a calculation to check if it is working. It is not. So what did I wrong?

Comment: @Prema You did not do anything wrong. If you quote the cell, the type is string. You can not calculate with strings. In order to calculate with strings, you have to remove the percent from the string and convert the string into a number. See here for details: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/07/18/excel-convert-text-to-number/

Comment: Yes, it calculates with string, which you clearly can see in my picture (not the yellow cells!). Try it yourself!

Comment: one can't open your sample file. This is still not clear for me why it should work for you and not for me.